# how to convert comma separated values to new line separated values in XSL

Tags: xslt

i have comma separated in that i want to convert them to line separated values
sample :

```
11,22,33,44,55
```

i want to convert them to

```
 11
 22
 33
 44
```

I've tried this function

```
oraext:create-nodeset-from-delimited-string
```

but it adds space between values instead of new line break .

using xsl.
is there any function that make desired output

Comment: BTW your output seems to be missing the last value, `55`.

Comment: What output method are you using? If it's HTML output and you want the output to look the way you've shown it, you need to generate `<br>` elements rather than newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT-1.0 you can use the `fn:translate(...)` function to convert all commas to newlines:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(value,',','&#xa;')" />
```

This doesn't remove leading and trailing spaces between the commas.

---

In XSLT-2.0, on the other hand, you can also remove those with a regular expression and the `fn:replace(...)` function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(value,'\s*,\s*','&#xa;')" />
```

---

If you try to create HTML output like mentioned in the comment above, you can use this recursive template to finish each number with a `<BR />` tag:

```
<xsl:template match="/*" name="strItem">
    <xsl:param name="str" select="concat(value,',')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring-before($str,',')),'&lt;br />')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring-after($str,','))">
        <xsl:call-template name="strItem">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str,',')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

With a `<value>11,22,33,44,55</value>` element (not at the root level), the output is

```
11<br />22<br />33<br />44<br />55<br />
```

Comment: it didn't work , it removed commas  and concat the values with no spaces

Comment: I updated my question. Did you try the new solution as well?